# how i use in c# form data send by ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have written this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("form").submit(function(){
             var form = $("form").serialize();
             $.ajax({
                   type:"post",
                   url: "App_Code/data.cs/myFunction",
                   data:form,
                   datatype:"json",
                   success: function
           });
     });
});
```

How do I get the posted form data in the C# function?

Comment: You want to do this in asp.net mvc or webForm?

Comment: i am not using mvs or webForm.
just code html get inputs in jquery and send by ajax to c#

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to set the url for the ajax call, how to process the form data on the server side, or how to access the returned data in the success function?

Comment: how to process the form data on the server side

Comment: To receive the data in the server side you must be using mvc or webforms or something-else. But there must be something. Just plain old c# won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call a function from the brower.

You need use with asp.net MVC.
Your function has to be part of a controller, so you can call it from the client side.

You have [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc) official documentation and [here](http://webmaster.org.il/articles/aspnetmvc) good tutorial in hebrew.

Comment: not right , i did with out data calling to function

Comment: right now you are not calling any function. Your function have to be a part of a controller.

Comment: i use service called "webMethod", i do not have any controller.

Comment: i success to call a function with data withput using mvc.
but it is not return data to jquery

Comment: you have to handle success function in jquery ajax call:

Comment: success: function(res) { // here you have your data}

Comment: i know but alert not working or console.log, how i know if i success to pass data form? because i put pointer in debugger and see the value and see the function return the object. but i do not know why not give me that data back in ajax.

Comment: You can check your sever return valid response in network tab or chrome.  You can use fiddler too.

Comment: thanks you, find it , why is not work, it is blocked and i do not know how to deal with it. i use fiddler, what i can do?